# DNS finds host only if domain name is included

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, domain, internal-dns

I have a Server 2012 DNS server on subnet `192.168.7.0` and I am trying to use that on a host on the `192.168.8.0` subnet, which is not on the domain (this may not be relevant).

When I configure the `192.168.8.x` host to only use the `192.168.7.10 DNS` server, I can find hosts in `nslookup` by searching for `computer1.mydomain.local` but I can't find them just by searching for `computer1`.

Why do I have to add `mydomain.local` in the `nslookup` or `ping`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Probably because you don't have any domain suffixes appended](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275553).

It's something you configure on the client, which doesn't magically know to append a DNS suffix to a hostname, unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question here.  If the PC is not on your domain, it will not append that domain name to DNS queries.  As a test, do a `ipconfig /all` and look for `DNS Suffix Search List` on that PC.  If you don't see anything there, your PC isn't going to append any DNS suffixes to queries.  Now do the same test from a PC on the domain and compare. You should see `mydomain.local` in the list on the PC that is on your domain.